# Can a child with accompanied visa travel back to home country with mother

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

My child visited me & my husband in the UK with accompanied visa. The adults accompanied was his grandparents. While returning to home country, instead of his grandparents(adults mentionedin his visa), can I (his mother) travel with him?

Comment: You don't need a visa to depart from a country. The visa conditions are for arriving.

Comment: As @Weather Vane states, the conditions are for entry. However it *might* be possible that you attract the attention of an Immigration officer, reviewing this https://www.gov.uk/permission-take-child-abroad might be useful

Comment: Yes, and proving you are legally responsible for a child on exit isn't really a visa issue.